# mysql caching from my own php function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, caching

Hello: I have function like this one

```
function query($query)
{
    if (in_array($query,$this->queries))
    {
            return $result = $this->results[$query];
    }

    $this->queries[] = $query;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result)
    {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
            {
                    $this->results[$query][] = $row;
            }

            //I need to return $result for later use (so I can loop it in while if i need to do so later)
            //but problem is that $result is being cleaned up after fetching

    }
}
```

does anybody/anyone know solution?

Comment: ? `return $result` does not work?

Comment: It does, but I can't use $result = query("SELECT * FROM test"); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){/* result is empty!*/}

Comment: You mean you wanna store your query and it's return results to reuse in future ?

Comment: @genesis: Ah I got it now.... because you sort of  consume the result set. Do you have to return the identifier or would the array of rows be fine?

Comment: what are the chances of your performing the exact same query over and over again within the same instance, I think this is pointless, at least have a file based storage system as disk read is much faster then network speed (if not hosted on the same server), otherwise look at memcached

Comment: Solution to what? What's the problem?

Comment: @Hamid: exactly @Felix: identifier so I can refetch it @Alexander: read code ... @RoberPitt: I do it many times in my application ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already getting an array of the results in the function so you shouldn't use `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Instead, just loop through the results (assuming there are results):

```
function query($query)
{
    if (in_array($query,$this->queries))
    {
        return $result = $this->results[$query];
    }

    $this->queries[] = $query;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
        {
            $this->results[$query][] = $row;
        }

        return $this->results[$query];
    }
}
```

And then use:

```
$result = query("SELECT * FROM test");

if(count($result) > 0)
{
    foreach($result as $key=>$value)
    {
        // Do what you need to with the rows
    }   
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use foreach, because I have to care about count($result) and many more aspects. I want to refetch it

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using a buffered query (i.e. mysql_query() instead of mysql_unbuffered_query()) you can reset the internal data pointer of the result set and use it (again) with mysql_fetch_...().

see http://docs.php.net/function.mysql_data_seek